# SFTP synchronization in PhpStorm 5 is too slow

Tags: deployment, synchronization, sftp, phpstorm

I'm testing new PhpStorm5 in Ubuntu 12.04. Synchronization via sftp works OK, but it is too slow. I have a feeling that phpStorm synchronizes via only one connection and doesn't create more concurrent connections to sftp. When I synchronize folders in Krusader sync plugin it uses 10 concurrent connections and works much faster. Any ideas how to force phpStorm deployment synchronization use more connections ?

Comment: Write to phpStorm developers and request a feature?

Comment: It is now December 2014, 3 years after the 2011 request for this. I don't think it's going to be implemented and, if it is, perhaps it's too late. I would recommend considering other IDEs with more basic features like this implemented. I doubt they'll be getting my money again next year.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not possible to use more connections, at least not until [this request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-5580) is addressed. The request is about FTP, but if/when it's implemented, it can be easily expanded to SFTP and other transports.

There is a setting to [limit concurrent connections](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/advanced-options-dialog.html), but it looks like only one connection is used when synchronizing.